Using a very very small learning rate to not diverge?
i just started with machine learning and today i tried implementing the gradient descent algorithm for linear regression. If i use a bigger value for alpha(the learning rate) the absolute value of w start increasing, diverging. Is having to use such a small number normal or did i make any mistakes?
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

def update_w(x,y,w,b,alpha):
    dj_dw = 0
    for i in range(m):
        y_guess = w * x[i] + b
        dj_dw = dj_dw + ((y_guess - y[i])*x[i])
    dj_dw = dj_dw/m
    w = w - alpha *dj_dw
    return w

def update_b(x,y,w,b,alpha):
    dj_db = 0
    for i in range(m):
        y_guess = w * x[i] + b
        dj_db = dj_db + ((y_guess - y[i]))
    dj_db = dj_db/m
    b = b - alpha *dj_db
    return b

#Training set
x_train = np.array([2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021,2022,2023])
y_train = np.array([100,99.4,105.2,118.7,107.7,106.2,106.3,116.5,112.9])

m=x_train.shape[0]

w=0
b=0
alpha = 0.0000001

for i in range(10000):
    temp_w = w
    temp_b = b
    w = update_w(x_train,y_train,temp_w,temp_b,alpha)
    b = update_b(x_train,y_train,temp_w,temp_b,alpha)

```


The instability comes from your x/y values having a very large magnitude. Training is better behaved if you rescale them to smaller values:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

def update_w(x,y,w,b,alpha):
    dj_dw = 0
    for i in range(m):
        y_guess = w * x[i] + b
        dj_dw = dj_dw + ((y_guess - y[i])*x[i])
    dj_dw = dj_dw/m
    w = w - alpha *dj_dw
    return w

def update_b(x,y,w,b,alpha):
    dj_db = 0
    for i in range(m):
        y_guess = w * x[i] + b
        dj_db = dj_db + ((y_guess - y[i]))
    dj_db = dj_db/m
    b = b - alpha *dj_db
    return b

#Training set
x_train = np.array([2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021,2022,2023])/1000
y_train = np.array([100,99.4,105.2,118.7,107.7,106.2,106.3,116.5,112.9])/100

m=x_train.shape[0]

w=0
b=0
alpha = 0.001

for i in range(10000):
    temp_w = w
    temp_b = b
    w = update_w(x_train,y_train,temp_w,temp_b,alpha)
    b = update_b(x_train,y_train,temp_w,temp_b,alpha)

Note the only changes to the code are dividing x_train by 1000, dividing y_train by 100, and increasing the learning rate to 1e-3
